# Am I still covered by my self-employed 401(k)?

Tags: united-states, ira, solo-401k

A couple years ago I setup a self-employed 401(k) plan (solo 401(k)) to handle retirement contributions made from a side hustle that my spouse and I both participated in as a qualified joint venture.  However, for 2018 the side hustle was dormant and we made nothing and won't be filing a schedule C.  The solo 401(k) is still active although we've made no contributions to it this year.

Am I still considered "covered by a retirement plan" when considering the income limits on making deductible contributions to a traditional IRA? At what point am I no longer covered, when I terminate the solo 401(k) plan?

Comment: How is the company organized?  Is the company still open?

Comment: My bad.  I thought I could simplify things to make this easier.  It's a qualified joint venture with my spouse.  I guess I'm not sure what it means to be "open".  I haven't done anything with the QJV in the past year. Do I need to take action to "close" the QJV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the IRS guidance on [Are You Covered by an Employer's Retirement Plan?](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/are-you-covered-by-an-employers-retirement-plan) (bold emphasis mine):

> You’re covered by an employer retirement plan for a tax year if your employer (or your spouse’s employer) has a:
>
> - Defined contribution plan (profit-sharing, 401(k), stock bonus and money purchase pension plan) **and** any contributions or forfeitures were allocated to your account for the plan year ending with or within the tax year;
> - IRA-based plan (SEP, SARSEP or SIMPLE IRA plan) and you had an amount contributed to your IRA for the plan year that ends with or within the tax year; or
> - Defined benefit plan (pension plan that pays a retirement benefit spelled out in the plan) and you are eligible to participate for the plan year ending with or within the tax year.

Also, from [General Instructions for
Forms W-2 and W-3: Form W-2 Box 13 Retirement Plan Checkbox Decision Chart](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw2w3.pdf):

> **Type of Plan:** Defined contribution plan (for example, a 401(k) or
>   403(b) plan, a Roth 401(k) or 403(b) account, but not a
>   457 plan)

---

> **Conditions:** Employee is eligible to contribute but does not elect to
>   contribute any money in this tax year
>
> **Check Retirement Plan Box?** No

---

> **Conditions:** Employee is eligible to contribute but does not elect to
>   contribute any money in this tax year, but the employer
>   does contribute funds
>
> **Check Retirement Plan Box?** Yes

---

> **Conditions:** Employee contributed in past years but not during the
>   current tax year under report
>
> **Check Retirement Plan Box?** No (even if the account value grows due to gains in the
>   investments)

So it looks like there's two conditions: (1) a defined plan in place AND (2) contributions made to one's account to be "covered by the plan".  In my case the second condition wasn't met so I wouldn't be "covered by the plan" even though it's still open.

Answer (score 2):

If it was me, I would work with the 401K provider and ask them if anything needs to be done formally.  Also you can close the business.  [SBA link to closing a business.](https://www.sba.gov/business-guide/manage-your-business/close-or-sell-your-business)  Once the business is closed the solo 401K does not exist, so you are not covered.

If you had this organized as an S-Corp this becomes a lot easier.  You can simply fire yourself, and then rehire as the opportunity presents itself.  You could have fired yourself on 12/31/2017 so you were not covered by a retirement plan for 2018.